# jquery.min.js is giving me a length error

Tags: jquery

I have the following script which seems to be causes errors in the jquery library:

```
$(".txtSearchBox").live('keyup', function() 
{ 

    if ($(this).closest('.portlet_72').find(".txtSearchBox").val().length > 0) {

        get_data_72( $(this), $(this).val() );

    } else {

        get_data_72();

    }

});
```

The dynamically generated HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="portlet_72>

    <div class="portlet_sub_header_72">
        <input type="text" class="txtSearchBox">
    </div>

    <div class="portlet_content_72"></div>

</div>
```

Why is this giving me the error `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` - jquery.min.js:3?

I have this code in another part of my site which is identical except for the 72, which is instead 71 and that part of the site does not give this error in jquery

I am using jquery 1.7.2

Comment: Either `.portlet_72` or `.txtSearchBox` is not being found in your traversal, hence `val()` is returning undefined, and `length` cannot be called on it. Without seeing your HTML, that's as much help as I can be.

Comment: `alert($(this).closest('.portlet_72').find(".txtSearchBox").length)`

Comment: `closest('.portlet_72').find(".txtSearchBox")` won't return you the serchbox. Since `.txtSearchBox` is not within `.portlet_72`. In fact, I don't see a `.portlet_72` at all in your markup.

Comment: Please post your complete html markup, you miss an element with  .portlet_72 class, without that your code will return undefined...with the current code you can simply refer to this http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/wxWp2/ ?

Comment: Added the .portlet_72 element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace

```
if ($(this).closest('.portlet_72').find(".txtSearchBox").val().length > 0) {
```

with

```
if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
```

since `this` already is the textbox.

Comment: I don't think I can do that.  I need to use the closest, because the HTML is based on user settings, and the user can choose to have the same portlet on the screen multiple times, which is why I originally used closest.

Comment: You bind the event to the textbox (`$(".txtSearchBox").live(...)`) so `this` is the textbox ...

Comment: Done, but it does't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: @oshirowanen after reading your question again, I saw `<div class="portlet_72>` is missing the closing quotes. That could lead to problems with the `closest` method.